# Synchronize node.js object

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I am using a variable and that is used by many functions at a time. I need to synchronize it. How do I do it?

```
var x = 0;

var a = function(){
  x=x+1;
}

var b = function(){
  x=x+2;
}

var c = function(){
  var t = x;
  return t;
}
```

This is the simplified logic of my code. To give more insight, X is as good as my mongoDB object which needs to be used by only one function at a time. Also 3 functions are like REST api calls so there is probability they will be called at same time.

I need to write getX function which should manage locking and unlocking.

Any suggestions?

Comment: couchdb tells you if you try to write an object that was updated since you accessed that object (i.e. the `_rev` property of the object you're trying to write doesn't match the current `_rev`. That gives me the opportunity to catch the error and recalculate my task with up to date object. Surely mongdoDB has some similar functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Node is single threaded so there is no chance of the the 3 functions to be executed at the same time. Syncronization and race conditions only apply in multithreaded environments. There is a case though, if the first function blocks for i/o.

Comment: yes. But what if all 3 functions are REST apis and might be called at same time. Any suggestion on that front?

Comment: This doesn't apply to node.js only. This should be generally true for JavaScript.

Comment: @Gaurav REST calls should be done in an asynchronous matter. Therefore only one result will return at a time. No problem there.

Comment: Actually I am facing this problem that REST calls are accessing common DB object and crashing due to race conditions.

Comment: You could use a normal variable as flag, so the other functions don't enter the critical section and have a timeout before retrying.

Comment: Please verify my posted answer.

Comment: I tried this with 1000 miliseconds but produces same issue. I tried earlier solution of calling XinUse = 0 in function A after getX, but that is causing "Range error: Stack exceeded.". I guess setTimeout is not working well. By giving 1000 delay I expect to see getX called after every 1 sec but it is called lot many times once it enter race condition.

Comment: Yes you are right, i will remove the code from my answer to avoid misleading others.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about keeping a single object synchronized as several
asynchronous operations modify that object. This is a bit vague (do you need to execute them in order? do they change the same properties?) Its hard to make a catch all solution, so I suggest that you determine what order, if any, the operations must take place in, and use the `async` library to handle
the control flow.

The `async.waterfall` method (example below) is useful if you want to pass
results down a chain of functions that execute in order. There are many other
useful functions included in the library, like `async.eachSeries` (execute a function once per array item in order) and
`async.parallel` (execute an array of functions simultaneously.) All docs available at https://github.com/caolan/async

```
var async = require('async');
function calculateX(callback){
  async.waterfall(
  [ 
    function(done){
      var x = 0;
      asyncCall1(x, function(x1){   // add x1=x+1;
        done(null, x1);
      });
    },
    function(x1, done){
      asyncCall2(x1, function(x2){   // add x2=x1+2;
        done(null, x2);
      });
    },
  ],
  function(err, x2){
    var t = x2;
    callback(t);
  });
};

calculateX(function(x2){
  mongo.save(x2, function(err){ // or something idk mongo
    if(err){ console.log(err) };
  });
});
```